# Не работает кнопка при нажатии

Tags: android, button

Здравствуйте не работает кнопка. Вот исходный код и логи, что выдаёт приложение после нажатия кнопки:
NewsActivity.java

```
 import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.all.news.AirCraft;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.all.news.Business;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.all.news.Car;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.all.news.Cinema;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.all.news.Clothes;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.all.news.Cyber_Sport;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.all.news.Heal;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.all.news.Music;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.all.news.PodCasts;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.all.news.Science;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.all.news.ShBs;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.all.news.Shares;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.all.news.Sport;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.all.news.Tech;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.all.news.TikTok;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.all.news.Update;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.all.news.Weather;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.all.news.YouTube;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    FirebaseAuth auth;

    public Button btn_settingss;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

        btn_settingss = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_settings);


        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);

        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
        String userid = firebaseUser.getUid();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userid).child("Interests");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    list.add(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                }

                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        if (list.get(position).equals("Подкасты")){
                            Intent intent_podcasts = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, PodCasts.class);
                            startActivity(intent_podcasts);
                        }else if (list.get(position).equals("КиберСпорт")){
                            Intent intent_cyber_sport = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, Cyber_Sport.class);
                            startActivity(intent_cyber_sport);
                        }else if (list.get(position).equals("Бизнес")){
                            Intent intent_business = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, Business.class);
                            startActivity(intent_business);
                        }else if (list.get(position).equals("Кино")){
                            Intent intent_cinema = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, Cinema.class);
                            startActivity(intent_cinema);
                        }else if (list.get(position).equals("ТикТок")){
                            Intent intent_tiktok = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, TikTok.class);
                            startActivity(intent_tiktok);
                        }else if (list.get(position).equals("Ютуб")){
                            Intent intent_youtube = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, YouTube.class);
                            startActivity(intent_youtube);
                        }else if (list.get(position).equals("Обновления")){
                            Intent intent_update = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, Update.class);
                            startActivity(intent_update);
                        }else if (list.get(position).equals("Музыка")){
                            Intent intent_music = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, Music.class);
                            startActivity(intent_music);
                        }else if (list.get(position).equals("Акции")){
                            Intent intent_shares = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, Shares.class);
                            startActivity(intent_shares);
                        }else if (list.get(position).equals("Одежда")){
                            Intent intent_clothes = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, Clothes.class);
                            startActivity(intent_clothes);
                        }else if (list.get(position).equals("Технологии")){
                            Intent intent_tech = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, Tech.class);
                            startActivity(intent_tech);
                        }else if (list.get(position).equals("Погода")){
                            Intent intent_tech = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, Weather.class);
                            startActivity(intent_tech);
                        }else if (list.get(position).equals("Машины")){
                            Intent intent_tech = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, Car.class);
                            startActivity(intent_tech);
                        }else if (list.get(position).equals("Шоу бизнес")) {
                            Intent intent_tech = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, ShBs.class);
                            startActivity(intent_tech);
                        }else if (list.get(position).equals("Спорт")) {
                            Intent intent_tech = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, Sport.class);
                            startActivity(intent_tech);
                        }else if (list.get(position).equals("Медицина")) {
                            Intent intent_tech = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, Heal.class);
                            startActivity(intent_tech);
                        }else if (list.get(position).equals("Наука")) {
                            Intent intent_tech = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, Science.class);
                            startActivity(intent_tech);
                        }else if (list.get(position).equals("Самолёты")) {
                            Intent intent_tech = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, AirCraft.class);
                            startActivity(intent_tech);
                        }
                    }
                });

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });



        btn_settingss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent_settings = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, Settings.class);
                startActivity(intent_settings);
            }
        });





    }



}
```

```
D/ViewRootImpl@6f05cf8[NewsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@6f05cf8[NewsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@6f05cf8[NewsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@6f05cf8[NewsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@6f05cf8[NewsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@6f05cf8[NewsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@6f05cf8[NewsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@6f05cf8[NewsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@6f05cf8[NewsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@6f05cf8[NewsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@6f05cf8[NewsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@6f05cf8[NewsActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
```

Comment: Откуда вызываете код, который приложили к вопросу?

Comment: Нужно больше подробностей. Так очень трудно понять, что за проблема. Покажите код активити. Те места где есть хоть какое-то взаимодействие с кнопкой

Comment: Скорее всего кнопка работает. Логи приведённые бесполезны - в них ничего нет. Выведите самостоятельно что-то в логи из колбэка нажатия - если вот этого в логах не будет, то тогда можно будет говорить, что нажатие не работает.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Я вызываю это в методе onCLick, а он Onclick в методе onCreate.

Comment: Приложите полный код, что-то белиберда какая-то получается

Comment: А не проще ли задать onClick в XML  для кнопки? И не нужно в активити уже onClickListener делать будет

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov обновил

Comment: `setContentView` Вы вызываете дважды, второй раз - уже после инициализации `btn_settingss`. Не уверен, как оно там работает под капотом в таких случаях, но очень похоже на причину бага

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ты два раза setContentView делаешь, и он вызывает второй раз без объявление кнопки, потому-что ты ее объявил до второго раза.(Он как бы перерисовывает, а обьявленая кнопка уже не действительна) Возможно что так.

Comment: Да, я только, что это сам увидел. Спасибо, за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

добавь в onClick  Log.d("ACTIVITY1","click button")  ,проверить работает или нет(в логах поищешь по ACTIVITY1, скорее всего она работает

Comment: Кнопка не работает.